# Is UnityAnswers using the Stack Overflow engine, hosted privately?

Tags: discussion

I was just looking at http://answers.unity3d.com/ and they seem to be using the Stack Overflow engine or Stack Exchange.

But it seems to be hosted on their servers. How is that possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was a Stack Exchange 1.0 site.

Checking the source shows the header:

```
<meta name="generator" content="StackExchange 0.9 (20100413135304-37b86aed49ad)">
```

NOTE: Unity Answers has since switched to the QATO backend. See the [Unity Answers FAQ](http://answers.unity3d.com/page/faq.html) about this.

Comment: Thx Chris for the info. So is that available under some commercial license that allows them to host on their own servers?

Comment: @Bach - it was the first attempt to spread the Stack Overflow model. It didn't work as expected so was replaced by the new Stack Exchange 2.0 [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Ah I see all clear now thx.